# Assign multiple classes to separate svg elements

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Have a hyperlink wrapped around and SVG rect element

```
<a href="elements/H.php"><rect x="48.9" y="84.3" class="st0 fancybox fancybox.iframe" width="96.3" height="96.3"/></a>
```

I'm trying to apply a second class called "fancybox fancybox.iframe" to the primary one class "st0". The second class should open the hyperlink in the iframe window above the parent page. As can be seen [here](http://chemistrytable.scienceontheweb.net/index_eng_svg.php), this doesn't work. A working example of what I'm trying to achieve is with area tag and is [here](http://chemistrytable.scienceontheweb.net/index.php).

According to [www.w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#ClassAttribute),

> Multiple class names must be separated by white space characters.

Problem being the white space in the class name? I've tried to put class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" in ID, svg and style, and it doesn't work. Ran out of ideas. I can't rename the class and make it without white spaces, since that would require renaming all references in javascript.

Comment: try to use `class="st0 fancybox iframe"` instead of `class="st0 fancybox fancybox.iframe"`

Comment: spaces are not valid in class names per https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-css3-syntax-20030813/#syntax

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Move `<g id="Elements">..</g>` little after in the SVG file and then do all like you did and put class on `a` elemenets, that's better I guess (sematically)

```js
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    afterShow: function() { 
        $('<div class="expander"></div>').appendTo(this.inner).click(function() {
            $(document).toggleFullScreen();
        });
    },
    afterClose: function() {
        $(document).fullScreen(false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.2.5/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.2.5/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1993.4 1123.4" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1993.4 1123.4;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 
 .st0{fill:#9B94C8;fill-opacity:0.62;stroke:#4A3F99;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st2{fill:#F15A29;fill-opacity:0.59;stroke:#D91F12;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st3{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#7B748A;stroke-width:0.75;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st4{fill:#F1F2F2;}
 .st5{font-family:'Georgia';}
 .st6{font-size:52px;}
 .st7{fill:none;}
 .st8{font-family:'TimesNewRomanPSMT';}
 .st9{font-size:19px;}
 .st10{font-size:21px;}
 .st11{font-size:12px;}
</style>
<g class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" id="Layer_1_1_">
</g>
<g id="Name">
 <rect x="61.6" y="145.3" class="st7" width="68.9" height="44.4"></rect>
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 61.6089 161.1328)" class="st8 st9">Водород</text>
</g><g id="Squares">
 <a href="elements/H.php" class="fancybox iframe st0"><rect x="48.9" y="84.3" class="st0 fancybox fancybox.iframe" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect></a>
 <rect x="1751" y="84.3" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <a href="elements/Li.php"><rect x="47.6" y="184.5" class="st2" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect></a>
 <rect x="149" y="184.5" class="st3" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1250.4" y="184.5" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1350.5" y="184.5" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1450.6" y="184.5" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1550.8" y="184.5" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1650.9" y="184.5" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1751" y="184.5" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="47.6" y="284.6" class="st2" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="149" y="284.6" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1250.4" y="284.6" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1350.5" y="284.6" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1450.6" y="284.6" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1550.8" y="284.6" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1650.9" y="284.6" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1751" y="284.6" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="47.6" y="384.7" class="st2" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="149" y="384.7" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="249.2" y="384.7" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="349.3" y="384.7" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="449.4" y="384.7" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="549.5" y="384.7" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="649.7" y="384.7" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="749.8" y="384.7" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="849.9" y="384.7" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="950" y="384.7" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1050.2" y="384.7" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1150.3" y="384.7" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1250.4" y="384.7" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1350.5" y="384.7" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1450.6" y="384.7" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1550.8" y="384.7" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1650.9" y="384.7" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1751" y="384.7" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="47.6" y="484.8" class="st2" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="149" y="484.8" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="249.2" y="484.8" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="349.3" y="484.8" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="449.4" y="484.8" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="549.5" y="484.8" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="649.7" y="484.8" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="749.8" y="484.8" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="849.9" y="484.8" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="950" y="484.8" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1050.2" y="484.8" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1150.3" y="484.8" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1250.4" y="484.8" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1350.5" y="484.8" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1450.6" y="484.8" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1550.8" y="484.8" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1650.9" y="484.8" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1751" y="484.8" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="47.6" y="584.9" class="st2" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="149" y="584.9" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="349.3" y="584.9" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="449.4" y="584.9" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="549.5" y="584.9" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="649.7" y="584.9" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="749.8" y="584.9" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="849.9" y="584.9" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="950" y="584.9" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1050.2" y="584.9" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1150.3" y="584.9" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1250.4" y="584.9" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1350.5" y="584.9" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1450.6" y="584.9" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1550.8" y="584.9" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1650.9" y="584.9" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1751" y="584.9" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="47.6" y="685.1" class="st2" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="149" y="685.1" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="349.3" y="685.1" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="449.4" y="685.1" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="549.5" y="685.1" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="649.7" y="685.1" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="749.8" y="685.1" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="849.9" y="685.1" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="950" y="685.1" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1050.2" y="685.1" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1150.3" y="685.1" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1250.4" y="685.1" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1350.5" y="685.1" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1450.6" y="685.1" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1550.8" y="685.1" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1650.9" y="685.1" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1751" y="685.1" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="349.3" y="835.2" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.4"></rect>
 <rect x="449.4" y="835.2" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.4"></rect>
 <rect x="549.5" y="835.2" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.4"></rect>
 <rect x="649.7" y="835.2" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.4"></rect>
 <rect x="749.8" y="835.2" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.4"></rect>
 <rect x="849.9" y="835.2" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.4"></rect>
 <rect x="950" y="835.2" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.4"></rect>
 <rect x="1050.2" y="835.2" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.4"></rect>
 <rect x="1150.3" y="835.2" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.4"></rect>
 <rect x="1250.4" y="835.2" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.4"></rect>
 <rect x="1350.5" y="835.2" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.4"></rect>
 <rect x="1450.6" y="835.2" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.4"></rect>
 <rect x="1550.8" y="835.2" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.4"></rect>
 <rect x="1650.9" y="835.2" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.4"></rect>
 <rect x="1751" y="835.2" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.4"></rect>
 <rect x="349.3" y="935.4" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="449.4" y="935.4" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="549.5" y="935.4" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="649.7" y="935.4" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="749.8" y="935.4" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="849.9" y="935.4" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="950" y="935.4" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1050.2" y="935.4" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1150.3" y="935.4" class="st1" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1250.4" y="935.4" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1350.5" y="935.4" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1450.6" y="935.4" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1550.8" y="935.4" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1650.9" y="935.4" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
 <rect x="1751" y="935.4" class="st1" width="96.4" height="96.3"></rect>
</g>
<g id="Elements">
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 76.6934 145.5522)" class="st4 st5 st6">H</text>
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 73.3599 244.2189)" class="st5 st6">Li</text>
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 65.0267 343.8855)" class="st5 st6">Na</text>
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 78.6932 441.2191)" class="st5 st6">K</text>
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 65.0266 545.2189)" class="st5 st6">Rb</text>
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 67.6932 641.5522)" class="st5 st6">Cs</text>
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 73.3601 737.2295)" class="st5 st6">Fr</text>
</g>

<g id="Number">
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 54.5679 103.6328)" class="st8 st10">1</text>
</g>
<g id="Atomic_x5F_masses">
 <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 110.8589 98.1328)" class="st8 st11">1.008</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ok. Something happens, but getting "The requested content could not be loaded" when pressing on the H rectangle. Link - http://chemistrytable.scienceontheweb.net/index_eng_svg.php
 Can you elaborate on next actions?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you have your file tree like this

```
-index.html
-css
  --Your .css files
-js
  --Your .js files
-elements
  --Your element.php pages
```

Why not make your rect files show a hidden div that loads your php page?

```
<a href="#" id="H" class="fancybox iframe st0 loader"><rect x="48.9" y="84.3" class="st0 fancybox fancybox.iframe" width="96.3" height="96.3"></rect></a>
```

The anchor tag would have the id of the element it presents, in this case, that`s H.
So now you can add a div that will load your page

```
<div class="hidden" style="position: fixed; z-index: 1000; width:100%; height: 100%; visibility: hidden;">
  <div class="page"></div>
</div>
```

And your jQuery would look like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".loader").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id')
    $(".hidden").show(function(){
      $(".page").load("path/to/"+id+".php");
    });
  });
})
```